# Read data from a SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a Table with the name "MyTable". I want to read the "Active3" column When the "ID3" column is an specified value. But I get this error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

```
    Dim con1 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    con1.Open()
    Dim sql1 As String = String.Format("SELECT Active3,DateTime3,BuyDateTime3 FROM MyTable WHERE ID3='{0}'", Session("lblID8"))
    Dim command1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql1, con1)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command1.ExecuteReader

    If reader.HasRows Then
        Label4.Text = reader("Active3")
    else 

    End If
   con1.Close()
```

Comment: and the exact error message is... ?

Comment: Start be telling us the error. Oh, and try debugging it yourself. So far the answer is "learn programming". The only answer possible given how much information you provide.

Comment: Also, [beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: try `If Reader.Read()` instead of `If reader.HasRows`.

Comment: **Please: Never never never** use anything like `WHERE ID3='{0}'`. You are opening up your database for attacks of the worst kind. Please look up how to use SQL parameters.

Comment: Do **not** use `string.Format()` to create SQL - this enables SQL Injection!

Comment: Thanks Zohar, But why when I delete the `if then` condition the error occurs?

Comment: @user1605859 Another example of information that we need to help you is the type of the "ID3" column in the database.

Comment: @user1605859 Please use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and correct the problems it shows you. You might then have working code just from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Using con1 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    con1.Open()
    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT Active3,DateTime3,BuyDateTime3 FROM MyTable WHERE ID3=@ID3"
    Dim command1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql1, con1)
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID3", Session("lblID8"))
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command1.ExecuteReader

    If reader.Read() Then
    Label4.Text = reader("Active3")
    else 

    End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Note: It's been a while since I've written VB.Net, there might be some mistakes here.

Explanations:

- The `Using` block handles disposable objects correctly.
- The use of parameters prevents Sql injection attacks
- Using `Reader.Read()` instead of `Reader.HasRows` in the condition enables you to get the value of the current record.

[`SqlDataReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record. It returns `true` if there are more records, and `false` otherwise.
When the SqlDataReader is created, the default position is **before** the first row, so you must call the `Read()` method to get the values of the first row.

Comment: It's been a while for me too, but isn't the Read() call required before you can use a DataReader anyway?

Comment: @AdamV: before you can access data, yes. from MSDN: "The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data."

Comment: There is an error in this line: `command1.Parameters.Add("@ID3" SqlDbType.int).Value = Session("lblID8")`

Comment: 'value' is not a member of 'integer'

Comment: make sure you are not missing the `)` between the `SqlDbType.int` and the `.Value`

Comment: then try `addWithValue` instead: `command1.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@ID3", Session("lblID8"))`

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks alot. But may I ask a question? Why should I use `IF` statement of What does actually do reader.read ?

Comment: See my edited answer. If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is probably not a good idea to expose users to `AddWithValue`: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Instead, `command1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ID3", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = CStr(Session("lblID8"))})` is more reliable. The problem there was probably not converting the Object `Session("lblID8")` to a integer, or string, or whatever the unspecified type of `ID3` is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton well, yes and no. I agree there is a problem with it and I can't remember the last time I've used it in my code. However, as I wrote, it's been a while since my vb.net days and it's an easier way then figuring out what went wrong with my first attempt when I can't debug the code myself.

Comment: I got  the first error again when I changed the value of session("ID3") which is exist  in another row of my table.

Comment: I don't know how does this relates to your question. there is no mention of session("ID3") in the code I've seen.

Comment: Please show the current code and the current error.